# lvalue argument for dispatch_semaphore_create ?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

What does the long value parameter signify in dispatch_semaphore_create ?

```
dispatch_semaphore_create(long value)
```

I didn't see this in the documentation, only examples of it being used with a zero argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `value` parameter is the initial value for the counting semaphore.

`dispatch_semaphore_wait()` decrements the semaphore count and waits if the resulting value is less than 0 (i.e. you can call `dispatch_semaphore_wait` four times without waiting on a semaphore created with value 4).

`dispatch_semaphore_signal()` increments the semaphore count and wakes a waiter if the resulting value is less than or equal 0.

See the `dispatch_semaphore_create(3)` manpage for a typical usage example (managing a finite resource pool).